# вопрос по Django, namespace

Tags: python, django

вот мои файлы:
urls.py основной

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('', include(('learning_logs.urls', 'learning_logs'), namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

urls.py не основной

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    #homepage
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

base.html

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>
</p>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Learning Log Helps you keep track of your learning, for any topic you're learning about.</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

в консоле выдает ошибку

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

это началось после того как я добавил `namespace='learning_logs'` в основной urls.py
это я сделал потому что на моем сайте выдавало `NoReverseMatch: 'learning_logs' is not a registered namespace` и решение этой проблемы было добавление namesapce но это вызвало другую ошибку, помогите разобраться

Comment: Указание пространства имен в include () без указания app_name не поддерживается. Задайте атрибут app_name во включенном модуле или передайте вместо него кортеж из двух частей, содержащий список шаблонов и app_name.

Answer (score 0):

я исправил свой не основной urls.py, теперь он выглядит так

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "learning_logs"

urlpatterns = [
    #homepage
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

вроде все работает, но я не знаю, костыль это или нет, не приведет ли это к другим ошибкам?

Comment: вы бы почитали документацию. в ней все подробно описывается. app_name для приложения задает как раз таки пространство имен. в include достаточно при этом одного аргумента

Comment: начните с туториала https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/intro/tutorial01.html

Comment: спасибо, сейчас этим и займусь